# Is it possible to combine backbone.js and Dojo.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dojo, arcgis-js-api

In my existing project, I have used backbone.js to develop the application based on the google maps. Now i want to develop the same application based on ArcGIS api for Javascript. ArcGIS api for javascript is built on the top of Dojo.js. Instead of google maps i have to use esri map using ArcGIS api for javascript. Now can I integrate backbone.js with Dojo.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Look at this article:

http://odoe.net/blog/getting-modular-with-the-arcgis-javascript-api/

You can also find some examples here: https://github.com/driskull/framework-samples-js